# Does Thrustmaster T-Flight Hotas 4 require PlayStation network subscription?

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus

I have read in a review about
Thrustmaster T-Flight Hotas 4, that PlayStation network subscription is required for the hotas to work on PS4, is this true?

Answer (score 0):

While it is stated that you need a PlayStation network account in the [manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1143382/Thrustmaster-T-Flight-Hotas-4.html?page=5#manual) for the Thrustmaster T-Flight Hotas 4, you do not need any subscription, as a PlayStation network account is free. If you do not know how to create a PlayStation network account, more information can be found on the official PlayStation website at this [link](https://www.playstation.com/en-us/support/account/create-account-for-psn/).